# Why the name of trucks are same in 2nd and 3rd record of company data retrieval?

Tags: php, database, mongodb, symfony, php-5.6

**My data in database:**

[image]

My objective is to retrieve all data of company collection (*MongoDB*) data from the database. The company collection holds one or many trucks. I have implemented one-to-many reference between company and trucks collection. That is working fine.
I am using query builder to get all the data. But, my code is not giving me all the Trucks of the specific company. It is retrieving only one truck name for specific documents.
My **API code** is checking the length of the truck's array and storing the name for the truck on **ta[]** array. Code is not written nicely as I have tried so many methods and I am frustrated now.
How can I retrieve my data?

**My API:**

```
 /**
     * @Route("/koco/get/company/query", name="queryToGetCompany")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function queryForCompanyAction()
    {

        $checkarray = array();
        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder(Company::class);
        $qb->find(Company::class);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $comapnies = $query->execute();
        
        foreach ($comapnies as $company)
        {
            $objectId =  $company->getId();
            $objectName = $company->getName();
            $objectAddress = $company->getAddress();

            // for length
            $len = count($company->getTrucks());
            echo $len;
            // For trucks
            $Trucks = $company->getTrucks();
            foreach ($Trucks as $truckname)
            {

                $ta = array();
                for($i=0;$i< $len;$i++){
                    $object = new Truck();
                    $object =  $truckname->getName();
                    $ta[] = $object;
                 }
            } 


            $checkarray[] = array(
            'Id' => $objectId, 
            'Name' =>$objectName, 
            'Address' =>$objectAddress, 
            'Trucks' => $ta,

        );
        }

        $data = [
            'Comapnies' => $checkarray,
        ]; 
        return new JsonResponse($data);

    }
```

**My results from the API:**

[image]

The 2nd and third companies are giving me the same records for the name of trucks, but in my database the truck names are different.

Comment: You have `foreach ($Trucks as $truckname) { $ta = array(); ...`. Try `$ta = array(); foreach ($Trucks as $truckname) { ...`. You're emptying `$ta` before adding it to `'Trucks' => $ta,`.

Comment: Hey, you said using Try $ta = array();
But, I also have used 
$ta = array();
Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: Sure...empty `$ta` BEFORE `foreach`. Not after.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It is working but now for the 2nd and 3rd companies I am getting  the results of Trucks 2 times like: "Volvo High-Efficiency Usage Truck",
"Volvo High-Efficiency Usage Truck",
"Volvo Low Efficient - STreet Truck",
"Volvo Low Efficient - STreet Truck". Also I have placed my $ta = array() right after forEach of $companies as $company. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach and your for loop are colliding, in conjunction with your array being emptied inside the foreach loop. If you reset your array before the foreach loop, not inside, and also just use a foreach without the for, I think this is what you want.

What is happening in your code as presented in the question is that the array is wiped out between trucks, so you only get the last truck. Additionally, because of the manually counted for loop, the number of copies of the last truck is equal to the total number of trucks associated with each company.

This is my suggestion based on what you have shown, replacing the entire foreach loop with this code.

```
$ta = array();

foreach ($Trucks as $truckname)
{
    $object = new Truck();
    $object =  $truckname->getName();
    $ta[] = $object;
}
```